# Policy exception for Windows User Account Controls and Update.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, group-policy, uac, executable

So... Apparently Windows has a list of filenames that require extra rights to run, included in this list is Update.exe, which happens to be the name of the file I'd like my clients to run without appealing to UAC.

I'd like to not give the advice "Just turn off UAC".

Is there a place in Windows Group Policies Editor (or whatever it's called since I switched to linux, where this kind of arbitrary file restriction is totally unheard of) where a sysadmin can say, "Turn off UAC for c:\xyz\update.exe"?

[Related question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222217/exe-name-like-update-exe-blocked-by-uac-in-scheduled-task)

Answer (score 2):

For windows updates you can allow non admins the ability to use the tool by configuring the policy 'Allow non-administrators to receive update notifications' (Available in Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Update).

To my knowledge there is no ability to turn off UAC prompting for a system defined EXE.

Comment: Aww man, isn't there a group policy for everything?